# Changing the initial letter of the day in datepicker

Tags: jquery, datepicker

You can change the initial letters of weeks in datepicker? Gave some research and read the documentation but have not found much information. Also researched the code some option and the one that came closest was "dayNamesMin", but still can not make changes. That's the part I want to change:

[image]

And this is the code with the options:

```
function K() {
        this.debug = false;
        this._curInst = null;
        this._keyEvent = false;
        this._disabledInputs = [];
        this._inDialog = this._datepickerShowing = false;
        this._mainDivId = "ui-datepicker-div";
        this._inlineClass = "ui-datepicker-inline";
        this._appendClass = "ui-datepicker-append";
        this._triggerClass = "ui-datepicker-trigger";
        this._dialogClass = "ui-datepicker-dialog";
        this._disableClass = "ui-datepicker-disabled";
        this._unselectableClass = "ui-datepicker-unselectable";
        this._currentClass = "ui-datepicker-current-day";
        this._dayOverClass =
            "ui-datepicker-days-cell-over";
        this.regional = [];
        this.regional[""] = {
            closeText: "Done",
            prevText: "Prev",
            nextText: "Next",
            currentText: "Today",
            monthNames: ["Janeiro", "Fevereiro", "Março", "Abril", "Maio", "Junho", "Julho", "Agosto", "Setembro", "Outubro", "Novembro", "Dezembro"],
            monthNamesShort: ["Jan", "Fev", "Mar", "Abr", "Mai", "Jun", "Jul", "Ago", "Set", "Out", "Nov", "Dez"],
            dayNames: ["Domingo", "Segunda", "Terça", "Quarta", "Quinta", "Sexta", "Sábado"],
            dayNamesShort: ["Dom", "Seg", "Ter", "Qua", "Qui", "Sex", "Sab"],
            dayNamesMin: ["Do", "Se", "Te", "Qa", "Qi", "Se", "Sa"],
            weekHeader: "FDS",
            dateFormat: "mm/dd/yy",
            firstDay: 0,
            isRTL: false,
            showMonthAfterYear: false,
            yearSuffix: ""
        };
```

Comment: Seems to work fine: http://jsfiddle.net/j08691/2MQnf/

Comment: Strangely not work for me. This code came from a ready template I bought.